# Hide several divs, show 1 by default, and switch (show/hide) between them based on link click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I know the show/hide thing has been covered to death on stack, but I just can't find a solution that works for me, sorry. I've tried several JS/jQuery solutions that I found and can't quite get one to behave the way I'd like.

I have many divs that are very similar in content (content changes slightly based on version selected), and all have the exact same style.

#### Desired behavior

I'd like one div to show by default with all others hidden. Then, based on a link click, a different version div is displayed and all other content divs are hidden.

#### Basic HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Basic info about page</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#ver1" id="linkToVer1">Version 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ver2" id="linkToVer2">Version 2</a></li>
    // More links to other divs
  </ul>

  <div class="content" id="ver1">    // I'd like this div to be the default
     Content here                    // when the page loads. All other divs 
  </div>                             // are hidden until a link is clicked.

  <div class="content" id="ver2">
     Content here
  </div>

  // More content divs
</div>
```

I'll have up to a dozen different versions of these content divs.

JS or jQuery is fine, but jQuery is preferred because I'll probably add some kind of show/hide effect. I don't care that greatly about the naming structure of the divs or links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div.containter ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).onclick(function(){

       $("div.content").hide();

      $("div" + $(this).attr("href")).show();

    });
});
```

Wrap that in a `$(document).ready` or whereever and you should be good to go my friend. Learn the code, so that in the future, you are gosu.

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin haha yeah that would be better. I went a little crazy for a moment.

Comment: I suppose you meant this: `$("div#" + $(this).attr("href")).show();`? EDIT: never mind, didn't read the begin post thoroughly.

Comment: @BramVanroy No i did not. That would result in `"div##1"`

Comment: @BramVanroy No problem. Thanks for looking over my syntax

Answer (score 0):

How about adding some more RESTful behaviour.

```
$(function(){
   // get the location hash
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   // hide all
   $('div.content').hide();
   if(hash){
      // show the div if hash exist
      $(hash).show();
   }else{
      // show default 
      $("#ver1").show();
   }
   $("div.containter ul li a").click(function(){
      // hide all
      $('div.content').hide();
      $($(this).attr("href")).show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `on()` jquery function with selector. And also you can show the default `div` using css. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rK4DD/4/) is the complete code.